# Issue with Xposed when developing android app

Tags: android, xposed

I run the APK(developed by **Android studio**) on my phone with **Xposd**,and there is something wrong.

Below is the **Error Console** that i am facing:

> 02-01 15:09:27.199 19563-19563/com.example.lizhe.materialcontacts
>   E/Xposed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
>                                                                                   at com.mhook.MrSFastTranslation.Moble.handleLoadPackage(Moble.java)
>                                                                                   at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage$Wrapper.handleLoadPackage(IXposedHookLoadPackage.java:34)
>                                                                                   at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.call(XC_LoadPackage.java:61)
>                                                                                   at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XCallback.callAll(XCallback.java:106)
>                                                                                   at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.XposedInit$2.beforeHookedMethod(XposedInit.java:116)
>                                                                                   at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:314)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication()
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5471)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.mhook.MrSFastTranslation-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
>   /system/lib64]]
>                                                                                   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285) 
>                                                                                   at com.mhook.MrSFastTranslation.Moble.handleLoadPackage(Moble.java) 
>                                                                                   at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage$Wrapper.handleLoadPackage(IXposedHookLoadPackage.java:34) 
>                                                                                   at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.call(XC_LoadPackage.java:61) 
>                                                                                   at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XCallback.callAll(XCallback.java:106) 
>                                                                                   at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.XposedInit$2.beforeHookedMethod(XposedInit.java:116) 
>                                                                                   at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:314) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication() 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5471) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                                   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102) 
>                                                                                 Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/system/framework/XposedBridge.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
>   /system/lib64]]
>                                                                                   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                         ... 20 more
>                                                                                     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager" on path:
>   DexPathList[[dex file
>   "/data/dalvik-cache/xposed_XResourcesSuperClass.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
>   /system/lib64]]
>                                                                                   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                             ... 21 more
>                                                                                         Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager
>                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                                 ... 22 more
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
>   boot class loader; no stack trace available

It runs correctly on the phone without **Xposed**.
How can I deal with it?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try running the app with `instant Run` disabled in Android Studio.

Comment: can you post your code? handleLoadPackage() will be enough